# Function Accepting Struct pointer and returning struct pointer has wierd behaviour?

Tags: c, pointers

I my code i call the insert function and it passes a pointer to the struct  (table) and the insert function recieves a pointer and does some stuff and returns it again. But running the code gives segmentation fault. when i try to access the values in the struct array using the pointer passed.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#define __USE_BSD
#include <string.h>

#include "speller.h"
#include "dict.h"

typedef struct 
{ // hash-table entry
  Key_Type element; // only data is the key itself
  enum {empty, in_use, deleted} state;
} cell;

typedef unsigned int Table_size; // type for size-of or index-into hash table

struct table 
{
  cell *cells; Table_size table_size; // cell cells [table_size];
  Table_size num_entries; // number of cells in_use
  // add anything else that you need
};

int hashfunc(Key_Type k, Table_size size)
{
    printf("enterd\n");
    char * d = k;
    int hash = 0;
    int c;
    printf("%s\n", d);
    printf("wtf??\n");
    while (c = *d++)
    {
        printf("maybehere??\n");
        hash = hash + c;
    }
    hash = hash%size;
    printf("%d\n", hash);
    return hash;
}

Table initialize_table (Table_size size) 
{
    Table t = malloc(sizeof(struct table));
    t->table_size = size;
    cell hash_table[size];
    for (int i=0; i<size; i++)
    {
        hash_table[i].state = empty;
        hash_table[i].element = "-";
        //printf("initialised\n");
    }
    t->num_entries = 0;
    t->cells = hash_table;
    /*for (int i = 0; i < t->table_size; i++)
    {
        printf("%d %s\n", i, (t->cells + i)->element);
    }*/
    return t;
}

int a = 0;
Table insert (Key_Type k, Table t) 
{
    //printf("insert called %d\n", a);
    printf("%d\n", t->table_size);
    //printf("%s\n", (t->cells + 2)->element);
    // as soon as program reaches here i get output like - 1 (NULL) 
    2 (NULL) and then segmentation fault
    for (int i = 0; i < t->table_size; i++)
    {
        printf("%d %s\n", i, (t->cells + i)->element);
    }
    a++;
    printf("%s\n", k);
    int hash_code = hashfunc(k, t->table_size);
    // Linear Probing
    printf("im here\n");
    while(strcmp((t->cells + hash_code)->element,"-") != 0)
    {
        if (strcmp((t->cells + hash_code)->element,k) == 0)
        {
            printf("return at if\n");
            return t;
        }
        else if (hash_code == (t->table_size - 1))
            hash_code = 0;
        else
            hash_code++;
    }
    (t->cells + hash_code)->element = k;
    (t->cells + hash_code)->state = in_use;
    t->num_entries += 1;
    printf("return at end with value %s\n", k);
    printf("inserted value %s\n", (t->cells + hash_code)->element);
    return t;

}

Boolean find (Key_Type k, Table t) 
{
    return FALSE;
}

void print_table (Table t) 
{
    Table_size size = t->table_size;
    for (int i = 0; i<size; i++)
    {
        if (strcmp((t->cells + i)->element,"-") != 0)
            printf("%d %s\n", i, (t->cells + i)->element);
    }
}

void print_stats (Table t) 
{
}

void main()
{

    Table table;
    Table_size table_size = 19;
    int a = 5;
    Key_Type input[5] = {"a","b","ab","abc","abcd"};
    table= initialize_table (table_size);
    //printf("%s\n", input[1]);
    while (a)
    {
        table= insert("a",table);
        a--;
    }
    printf("printing table\n");
    print_table(table);
}
```

this is the dict.h code

```
typedef char* Key_Type;
typedef struct table* Table;    // allows different definitions of struct table

Table initialize_table ();      // allows different parameters
Table insert (Key_Type, Table);
Boolean find (Key_Type, Table);
void print_table (Table);
void print_stats (Table);
```

This is the speller.h code

```
typedef enum {FALSE, TRUE} Boolean;

extern int verbose; // used to control monitoring output
extern int mode;    // used to control your algorithm

extern char *prog_name; // used by check

void check (void *memory) ; // check result from strdup, malloc etc.
```

I believe i dont understand how the pointers work in this program.

Comment: Don't `typedef` pointers, that's bad practice. You got me lost for a while, I didn't fined the `typedef` but I noticed you used the `->` operator to access members. Also, consider checking if `malloc()` returned non-`NULL` pointer.

Comment: Isn't your compiler throwing warnings when compiling this code?

Comment: i dnt get any warnings no

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the problem,

```
cell hash_table[size];
```

and then, you make `t->cells` point to `hash_table` but `hash_table` is a local variable in the `initialize_table()` function, so it's destroyed/deallocated when the function returns and no longer accessible after it returns.

You should allocate it on the heap too, like this

```
cell *hash_table;
hash_table = malloc(size * sizeof(*hash_table));
if (hash_table == NULL)
    return NULL; // Probably free `t' so that no memory leaks
                 // happen
```

Accessing such a local variable that was allocated in the stack frame of a function, after that function returns is *undefined behavior*, the problem could happen somewhere else in the code or when accessing the pointer pointing to the deallocated data.

***A side note***

Be consistent with naming, and unambigous, you used a weird CamelCase and underscore combination, it doesn't matter if it's weird or not, keep it and preserve it throughout the code — *respect your own style*. And call the `cell` `typedef`: `Cell` instead.

Also, always check the return value of `malloc()` which returns `NULL` on error (*allocation failure*), you should write code as if all the bad things will happen, because they do.

And finally, never `typedef` a pointer. It doesn't help whatsoever, it only obscures the fact that a declaration is that of a pointer.

Comment: also how do i free t if i am actually returning it??

Comment: Later you call a function `free_table(t);` that does all the *free*ing.